# How can I tell Chrome which input fields to remember / which will be the login credentials?

Tags: forms, login, input-fields, html, chrome

I have a Sign Up form which contains these input fields (in order):

- **e-mail** (autocomplete="email", type="email")
- **(user)name** (type="text")
- **(display)name** (type="text")
- **password** (autocomplete="new-password",type="password")
- **password again** (type="password")

If the user submits this form, Chrome suggests to **save the password** but paired with the **name(s)** instead of the **e-mail field** (which will be needed to login). How can I tell Google Chrome (and other browsers) which input fields to remember / which will be the login credentials? (in my case: e-mail and password). Is there some kind of HTML5 code for this?

I have tried so far:

- autocomplete="false" , autocomplete="off"  and autocomplete="new-password" on the name fields ( Not working)
- autocomplete="false", autocomplete="off" on the signup form itself (not working)
- give an unrecognizable id and name to the name fields (id="usnm" instead of id="username") (not working)

I need to achieve:

- Tell the browser that DO NOT remember the sign up form input values as credentials OR
- Tell the browser exactly which data values to remember (e-mail + pass)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is coding problem, please post it in correct section

Comment: Why is the user submitting a username if it's not used to log in?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that this is not the right forum, but unfortunately, no one could help me at the coding forum so this is why I posted this here ( I thought as a UI/UX developer this problem may come through once in a while in some form so it worth a shot). Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HTML, label the email field "username", both name and ID attributes. Use "Email" as the label that the user sees. They will be setting a login that is an email.

Don't capture a separate username, as that might be confusing ("Which do I log in with?") Use Display Name as a handle that will be used throughout the site.

Comment: Thank you Stacy, your solution saved my life! (It worked like a charm!) 
Ps: I need usernames because I use them as user ID's (in URLs mainly) instead of the real (numeric) ones. I thought users will appreciate the opportunity to choose one for themselves instead some random numbers and letters - but maybe this wasn't the best idea.